# QGIS (3.32.0) not recognizing some feature classes in file geodatabase created by ArcGIS Pro (3.2.49)

Tags: qgis, arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

At work I have been using QGIS and storing all my data in GeoPackages for the past year. GeoPackages don't allow feature datasets to my knowledge, so when my office got ArcGIS Pro I was excited to start better organizing our data. I work for a local government agency so being able to create datasets for infrastructure, projects, and administrative boundaries with feature classes nested within the was hugely appealing.

It was easy enough to do the conversion and I now have everything organized in a file geodatabase. I am able to load and view everything while using ArcGIS Pro. However, I still have coworkers who use QGIS and they are having trouble. I was able to replicate their issues on my own copy of QGIS as well. It seems that about half of the feature classes, when added to QGIS, show 0 feature and nothing in the attribute table. However, when I am using ArcGIS Pro I am able to see and interact with all the features normally. There does not appear to be any sort of pattern that I can discern as to why some feature classes have this issue and others do not.

Through my research it does not appear there should be any issues with QGIS reading file geodatabases created by ArcGIS Pro. Does anyone have any idea for settings I should be looking at as a potential cause for this issue?

Comment: Is the feature dataset this thing https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/feature-datasets/feature-datasets-in-arcgis-pro.htm? Could you make some small filegdb that shows the issue? Use open datasets, for example OpenStreetMap, if you cannot share your own data.

Comment: It is just a catalog dataset (I believe that is the correct term). Basically, it just functions as a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have not found a workaround, but the issue comes with the latest version of ArcGIS Pro. The ObjectID Data Type of all the features that do not load in the geodatabase are 64bit while all the ones that do work are 32bit. It appears that while I was bringing the layers into the Geodatabase that I somehow upgraded the ObjectID data to 64bit, which evidently does not work with QGIS.

[image: ObjectID Data Source Issue]

Comment: According to [ESRI File Geodatabase vector (OpenFileGDB) - GDAL  documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/openfilegdb.html#bit-integer-field-support), 64-bit integer field support is coming in GDAL 3.9 (expected release May 2024), and then eventually into a future release of QGIS.

Answer (score 0):

I was going through a similar process of migrating old shapefiles to a file geodatabase using ArcGIS Pro. I've also been unable to use some of my feature classes in QGIS or MapServer as they show 0 records in the dataset that displays properly in ArcGIS Pro. My ObjectID is 32-bit, however. I figured out my issue was due to using the newer "date only" date field. I tried to export my fgdb feature class to a shapefile and got an error that the date only field type isn't supported. I deleted those fields and now all records show up and the feature class displays properly in QGIS and MapServer. I may need to migrate those date only fields to a date field.